# Passing data to activity from threaded service

Tags: android, multithreading, service, android-activity

How can I pass data from a threaded service to the activity that created the service?

It's a login scenario. The user enters credentials, the activity starts a service which calls an wcf service to confirm the credentials. When this is done I want the service to tell the activity that the login has succeeded/failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to perform the login check. It is recommended to show a dialog while performing long work, see the [example](http://it-projects.spb.ru/?p=150&lang=en) with progress dialog.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I was just checking out AsyncTask instead of a service.

Comment: @Vladimir: But the examples suggest that I would put the AsyncTask class as a private class in my activity class, right? I'd rather break it out into a seperate class. So the question kind of remains - how can I reach the activity from the AsyncTask?

Comment: @Clark Kent, You can organize sort of callback. Create a method `onLogin(boolean result);` in your activity and pass an instance of it to the AsyncTask. So, in onPostExecute() you will be able to call `activity.onLogin(result);`.

Comment: @Vladimir, and if I my memory don't fail me, onPostExecute can make this call in a thread safe way?

Comment: yes, you're totally right. This method is executed in UI thread.